# Can I use a controller inside another controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, controller, server

I'm developing an application, I want to use a controller functions inside another controller function. How can this be done? Or it can't?

**Use-case:** I want to check in the User collection (using mongoDB) if the user has the permission to post another Patient in the Patient collection. I want to implement somekind of Price Plan approach to my application.

Any doubt or advice, please comment I will gladly answer.
Thank you.

**user.controller:**

```
'use strict';
/**
 * module dependencies
 */
const User = require('../models/user');
const Utilities = require('../models/utilities');
var errHandler = Utilities.errHandler;
var validationErr = Utilities.validationErr;

module.exports = {
    getAll: getAll,
    put: put,
    post:post,
    deleteUser: deleteUser,
    updateLastLoginDate: updateLastLoginDate,
    get: get,
    patch:patch
}
/**
 * GET user
 */
function get(req, res) {
    if (req.user._id == req.params.id) {
        return User.findById({ _id: req.params.id }, 'email', (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400);
            }
            if (user) {
                return res.json(user);
            } else {
                return res.status(404);
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(403);
    }
}
```

**patient.controller:**

```
'use strict';
/**
 * module dependencies
 */
const Patient = require('../models/patient');
const UserController = require('./user.controller');
const Utilities = require('../models/utilities');
const Logger = require('../config/logger');
var errHandler = Utilities.errHandler;
var validationErr = Utilities.validationErr;

module.exports = {
    getAll: getAll,
    post: post,
    getByNumber: getByNumber,
    getByName: getByName
}
/**
 * Post patient
 * @param id
 */
function post(req, res, done) {
    // Check if user has access to the patient
    if (req.user._id == req.params.id) {
        return Patient.findById({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, patient, done) => {
            if (err) {
                Logger.debug("userId: %s | error:%s | error in finding patient", req.params.id, err);
                return res.status(404);
            }
            var user = UserController.get(req,res);
            Logger.debug("userId: %s | variable %s", req.params.id, a);
            // Do if user.pricePlan.maxPatients < patients.count
            if (patient) {
                patient.name = req.body.name;
                patient.email = req.body.email;
                patient.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
            } else {
                var patient = new Patient();
                patient.name = req.body.name;
                patient.registeredIn = new Date();
                patient.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
                patient.userId = req.params.id;
            }

            patient.save((err, patient) => {
                if (err) {
                    Logger.debug("userId: %s | error:%s | error in saving patient", req.params.id, err);
                    return res.status(404);
                }
                Logger.debug("userId: %s | patientId: %s | saving patient", req.params.id, patient._id);
                return res.json(patient);
            });
        });
    } else {
        Logger.debug("userId: %s | jwt: %s | trying create patient without permission", req.params.id, req.headers.authorization);
        res.status(403);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, your `UserController.get()` method does not return anything. It just either sends a HTTP response with the user JSON or a 4xx status code. So the way that you're using it in `patient.controller` would cause the `post` method to prematurely send a response to the client.

I'm not sure how the rest of your app is implemented, but you may want to
consider writing a middleware method that is called before the `post` that checks if the user has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Shaka thank you for your asnwer. The middleware is the function I'm trying to implement, checking the price plan. But I'm trying to use the User Controller that is the responsible for the User Collection queries..